# php pos system: when scanning a product that its not found in the database it adds a product starting with the same digits, i need to solve this

Tags: javascript, php, point-of-sale

the automatic submission works by adding product to sales entered from a list according to the barcode entered using barcode scanner, but when if a product is not found in the database it adds a product that start with the same first digits of that product, so I need to solve this problem.
I tried do make a check product code and access to it from a JavaScript inside this script but it doesn't work, I think the problem is because the automatic submission mechanism but I don't know how to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>POS</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="vendors/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/DT_bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="../style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!-- JavaScript -->
 <script src="lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendors/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> <!-- Remove this line, as jQuery is already loaded above -->
<script src="src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendors/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
      loadingImage : 'src/loading.gif',
      closeImage   : 'src/closelabel.png'
    });
  });
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding-top: 60px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .sidebar-nav {
      padding: 9px 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <?php include('navfixed.php'); ?>

  <?php
     

    $position = isset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']) ? $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] : '';

    if ($position == 'cashier') {
      ?>
      <a href="sales.php?id=cash&invoice=<?php echo $finalcode ?>">Cash</a>
      <a href="../index.php">Logout</a>
      <?php
    }
    if ($position == 'admin') {
      ?>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span2">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
              <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li><a href="index.php"><i class="icon-dashboard icon-2x"></i> Dashboard </a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="sales.php?id=cash&invoice=<?php echo $finalcode ?>"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-2x"></i> Sales</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.php"><i class="icon-list-alt icon-2x"></i> Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="customer.php"><i class="icon-group icon-2x"></i> Customers</a></li>
                <li><a href="supplier.php"><i class="icon-group icon-2x"></i> Suppliers</a></li>
                <li><a href="salesreport.php?d1=0&d2=0"><i class="icon-bar-chart icon-2x"></i> Sales Report</a></li>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <li>
                  <div class="hero-unit-clock">
                    <form name="clock">
                      <font color="white">Time: <br></font>&nbsp;<input style="width:150px;" type="text" class="trans" name="face" value="" disabled>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.well -->
          </div><!--/span-->

          <div class="span10">
            <div class="contentheader">
              <i class="icon-money"></i> Sales
            </div>
            <ul class="breadcrumb">
              <a href="index.php"><li>Dashboard</li></a> /
              <li class="active">Sales</li>
            </ul>

            <div style="margin-top: -19px; margin-bottom: 21px;">
              <a href="index.php">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-large" style="float: none;">
                  <i class="icon icon-circle-arrow-left icon-large"></i> Back
                </button>
              </a>
            </div>

            <form action="incoming.php" method="post" id="barcodeForm">
              <input type="hidden" name="pt" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
              <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $_GET['invoice']; ?>" />

              <select name="product" style="width: 650px;" class="chzn-select" required autofocus>
  <?php
  include('../connect.php');
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
  $result = $db->query($sql);

  if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $row['product_code'] . ' - ' . $row['product_name']; ?>
      </option>
      <?php
    }
  } else {
    ?>
    <option value="" disabled>No products found</option>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
</select>


              <input type="number" name="qty" value="1" min="1" placeholder="Qty" autocomplete="off" style="width: 68px; height:30px; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom: 4px; margin-right: 4px; font-size:15px;" required>
             
              <Button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 123px; height:35px; margin-top:-5px;" /><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i> Add</button>
            </form>

            <table class="table table-bordered" id="resultTable" data-responsive="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Product Name</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Qty</th>
                  
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php
                $id = $_GET['invoice'];
                include('../connect.php');
                $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales_order WHERE invoice= :userid");
                $result->bindParam(':userid', $id);
                $result->execute();
                for ($i = 1; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
                  ?>
                  <tr class="record">
                    <td hidden><?php echo $row['product']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                      <?php
                      $ppp = $row['price'];
                      echo $ppp;
                      ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['qty']; ?></td>
                    
                    
                    
                    <td width="90">
                      <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['transaction_id']; ?>&invoice=<?php echo $_GET['invoice']; ?>&dle=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&qty=<?php echo $row['qty']; ?>&code=<?php echo $row['product']; ?>">
                        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-warning"><i class="icon icon-remove"></i> Cancel</button>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                }
                ?>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                   
                  
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="3">
                    <strong style="font-size: 12px; color: #222222;">Total:</strong>
                  </th>
                  <td colspan="1">
                    <strong style="font-size: 12px; color: #222222;">
                      <?php
                      function formatMoney($number, $fractional = false) {
                        if ($fractional) {
                          $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
                        }
                        while (true) {
                          $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
                          if ($replaced != $number) {
                            $number = $replaced;
                          } else {
                            break;
                          }
                        }
                        return $number;
                      }
                      $sdsd = $_GET['invoice'];
                      $resultas = $db->prepare("SELECT price, qty FROM sales_order WHERE invoice= :a");
                      $resultas->bindParam(':a', $sdsd);
                      $resultas->execute();
                      $totalprice = 0;
                      for ($i = 0; $rowas = $resultas->fetch(); $i++) {
                        $gg = $rowas['price'];
                        $dd = $rowas['qty'];
                        $total = (float)$gg * (float)$dd;
                        $totalprice += $total;
                        
                      }
                      echo '$' . number_format($totalprice, 2);
                      ?>
                    </strong>
                  </td>
                  <td colspan="1">
                    <strong style="font-size: 12px; color: #222222;">
                      <?php
                      $resulta = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(profit) FROM sales_order WHERE invoice= :b");
                      $resulta->bindParam(':b', $sdsd);
                      $resulta->execute();
                      for ($i = 0; $qwe = $resulta->fetch(); $i++) {
                        $asd = $qwe['sum(profit)'];
                       
                      }
                      ?>
                    </strong>
                  </td>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table><br>

            <form action="checkout.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $_GET['invoice']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $totalprice; ?>" /> <!-- Use $totalprice here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="pt" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cashier" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="totalprof" value="<?php echo $asd; ?>" />

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-large btn-block" type="submit">
        <i class="icon icon-save icon-large"></i> SAVE
    </button>
</form>




            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>

  <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
  <script>
  const barcodeForm = document.getElementById('barcodeForm');
  let submissionTimeout;

  document.addEventListener('input', () => {
    clearTimeout(submissionTimeout); // Clear any existing timeout
    submissionTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      barcodeForm.submit();
    }, 500); // Set a delay of 500 milliseconds
  });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
  <script>
  const barcodeForm = document.getElementById('barcodeForm');
  let submissionTimeout;

  document.addEventListener('input', () => {
    clearTimeout(submissionTimeout); // Clear any existing timeout
    submissionTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      barcodeForm.submit();
    }, 500); // Set a delay of 500 milliseconds
  });
</script>

Comment: If you have more code to share, you need to [edit] your question, then you can show it properly formatted, in context with everything else. As you can see, code in comments is unformatted and hard to read. See also [ask] and the [tour] please, to understand how stackoverflow works.

Comment: `but when if a product is not found in the database it adds a product that start with the same first digits of that product`...ok. But what do you want to happen instead? You didn't really explain. Also, what debugging have you done so far? Try and narrow the issue down a bit. There is a lot of code and very little information about it. Remember we mostly cannot run your code, so you need to try and debug it and find out more precisely where its behaviour starts to deviate from your expectation. At that point, we can then help you to fix the specific issue you've noticed.

Comment: `it adds a product`...to where? You mean it adds to the database? Or to some list on the display? Please be clear and specific when you are describing the situation.